# Complex networking in MIDP: how to close a URLConnection

Tags: java, networking, midp

I'm trying to write a MIDP application which is doing lots of networking. This is all being done via HttpURLConnection (which is all this platform supports; Socket doesn't work). The main part that's causing problems is code to tunnel an InputStream and an OutputStream across a set of HTTP connections, so that each read and write turns into a separate POST request.

I'm finding that while doing networking in MIDP isn't too bad, *stopping* doin networking in MIDP is a nightmare. I'm finding I'm ending up with lots of threads all of which are blocked on read() or write(), and finding them all and killing is really hard. It doesn't help that Thread.interrupt() doesn't work in Java's InputStream.read() and OutputStream.write(), and calling close() on the Stream isn't always possible because the stream might be hidden away inside URLConnection, and URLConnection itself doesn't have any way to tell it to close the connection.

It doesn't help that my platform is insanely picky about cleanup. If I, e.g., leave a thread running when the application exits the system reboots. I suspect that it's running my midlet in the same VM as the main device UI.

So: can anyone suggest a suitable structure that I should adopt to make this sort of thing easier? Because right now it's turning into a fractal maze of threads and catch blocks and interrupts and IOExceptions and I'm rapidly losing track of how it's supposed to work.

Alternatively, a nice event-driven IO library that wraps URLConnection would be handy. Alas, this is MIDP, so nio or channels or anything like that aren't an option.

**Edit:** Update: it turns out that it's *not* MIDP after all, it's PBP 1.1. Ah, the joys of inadequate documentation. Still, they're not too dissimilar, and the vendor *has* told us that the only networking system that works is HttpURLConnection.

Comment: I assume you are refering to the MIDP Connection and HttpConnection instead of the Java SE URLConnection and HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting --- I *am* referring to URLConnection. The device in question is exceedingly odd and has a thoroughly customised MIDP implementation (hence a lot of my pain); I don't have a definitive list of what classes are supported. Obviously they're mixing in some SE stuff. Is this going to make my job harder or worse...?

Comment: Much worse; since I guess this implies you are stuck with a single device, and it does not work. You should check out if some type of threads (like from system events) cannot do networking - however you are probably seeing the network modules crashing, deep, deep within the device, and out of your reach. Update to the latest firmware or file a bug. You have my sympaties..

Answer (score 1):

You will experience different network problems not only with different phones, but also with different configurations and carriers, firmware, networks and network conditions.

That said, you are free to implement an HTTP client using sockets - your assumption is not true on all but the oldest phones. Also you should have a look at the Connection.close() method. I am currently using the following close method, which is simple but effective:

```
public void close() {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inputStream = null;
        }
    }
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            outputStream = null;
        }
    }
    if (connection != null) { 
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection = null;
        }
    }
    closed = true;
}
```

If this does not work, you are doomed. In other words, you should not assume that you will be able to get your MIDP working flawlessly on all MIDP phones - because you will not. Design for the bigger picture, do not spend time debugging hopelessly flawed MIDP implementations.

You might want to synchronize.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out I'm not using MIDP's Connection, I'm using Java SE's URLConnection (which they have somehow wedged onto the device). Sorry for the confusion. URLConnection has no close() method, although HttpURLConnection has a disconnect(), but that doesn't do what I want... any ideas?